# Javascript Map returns undefined although (key, value) pair defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running this code snippet in linux terminal using nodejs. Although the (key, value) pair is correctly set, the code prints undefined. Any explanation or work around for this problem?

```
function trial() {
    var obj1 = {};
    var obj2 = {};
    obj1.fund = 1;
    obj1.target = 2;
    obj2.fund = 1;
    obj2.target = 2;
    states = [];
    states.push(obj1);
    states.push(obj2);
    actions = [1,2,3,4];
    table = new Map();
    for (var state of states) {
        for (var action of actions) {
            cell = {};
            cell.state = state;
            cell.action = action;
            table.set(cell, 0);
        }
    }
    var obj = {};
    obj.state = states[1];
    obj.action = actions[1];
    console.log(table.get(obj));   
}
```

Comment: What are you returning?

Comment: this code does not return anything. You are obviously talking about console.log. Did you try to simplify this ugly piece of code? While doing so, you might find what is wrong

Comment: why would you expect `table.get(obj)` to return anything when you have `var obj = new Object()` (note: that's what `var obj = {}` is shorthand for).

Comment: My apologies, I was talking about console.log. Basically, I wanted to create a mapping and then later query it. But even with identical data, the mapping was returning undefined. I am new to javascript, so had some trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the original object reference to match the key in table(`Map()`), let's hold every new `cell` which is each object reference to show that.

And even you have a deep clone of object, to `Map()`, it is not the same key.

```js
     var obj1 = {};
     var obj2 = {};
     obj1.fund = 1;
     obj1.target = 2;
     obj2.fund = 1;
     obj2.target = 2;
     states = [];
     states.push(obj1);
     states.push(obj2);
     actions = [1,2,3,4];
     table = new Map();
     var objRefs = [];
     var count = 0;
     for (var state of states) {
         for (var action of actions) {
             cell = {};
             cell.state = state;
             cell.action = action;
             table.set(cell, count);
             objRefs.push(cell);  //hold the object reference
             count ++;
         }
     }
     
     for (var i = 0; i < objRefs.length; i++) {
       console.log(table.get(objRefs[i]));
     }

     // Copy by reference
     var pointerToSecondObj = objRefs[1]; 
     
     console.log(table.get(pointerToSecondObj));
     
     //Deep clone the object
     var deepCloneSecondObj =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objRefs[1]));
 
     console.log(table.get(deepCloneSecondObj));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. You will probably get what you need. I did a small beautify.

```
function trial() {
    var obj1 = {
            fund: 1,
            target: 2
        },
        obj2 = { 
            fund: 1,
            target: 2
        },
        obj = {},
        states = [
            obj1, obj2
        ],
        actions = [1,2,3,4],
        table = new Map(),
        cell
    ;
    for (var state of states) {
        for (var action of actions) {
            cell = {};
            cell.state = state;
            cell.action = action;
            table.set(cell, 0);   
        }
    }
    obj.state = states[1];
    obj.action = actions[1];
    return(obj);
    //console.log(table.get(obj));   
}
console.log(trial())
```